# aws-cli portable for windows?

Tags: aws-cli, portable-applications

this is probably not a big issue for most people but do you know if there is anywhere a portable version for windows of aws-cli.

This because some people might want to install it for example in company laptops and not have admin rights to do it so I was wondering if I could find a portable version somewhere.

---

### edit

could not find a proper portable software version for it but if you manage to install python and use pip then the installation following the instructions in [github](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/tree/master) are quite easy.

### final update

I was quite lucky because my company just introduced python as a tool that they allow us to install so I managed to use pip.
the only thing I needed to consider was the user flag so it installs where I have permissions:

```
pip install --user awscli
pip install --target=YOUR_PATH awscli
```

Comment: "portable" as in 'does not need to be installed/can run from a thumb drive/etc.' ?

Comment: yes that is normally the definition of portable no? :)
i took a look at the github project actually but not sure i know how to build it on my windows machine, but that might be my next option, mainly i might be able to compile it just not sure about the configs

Comment: found out that once I installed pip was quite easy to get this from the repository so I guess this is not really needed

Comment: Assuming you'll always have Python. You could also use `boto3` in a virtualenv.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is how I've gotten around this issue in the past:

I downloaded (.msi) and install AWS CLI onto my personal laptop then I copy this entire directory (/Amazon/AWSCLI/..) to my corporate laptop where I don't have Admin rights. Then you can either temporarily update the PATH environment variable in your cmd/powershell session or you can permanently update your user variable's PATH to include the location of aws.exe.

It appears you will have to use the aws.exe under /bincompat (instead of /bin) as of their newest release. I haven't yet tested this version to see what limitation exists.

Answer (score 17):

As of April 2021, there is only awscli version 1 available in pip repositories. If you want to use awscli version 2 but you don't want to use chocolatey or you don't have another windows machine available, you can:

- download the `.msi` file from Amazon website: https://awscli.amazonaws.com/AWSCLIV2.msi
- use `msiexec` in command line to extract application from msi package:

```
msiexec /a %USERPROFILE%\Downloads\AWSCLIV2.msi /qb TARGETDIR=%USERPROFILE%\awscli
```

Now you can use awscli version 2 using the following command:

```
>%USERPROFILE%\awscliv2\Amazon\AWSCLIV2\aws --version
aws-cli/2.1.39 Python/3.8.8 Windows/10 exe/AMD64 prompt/off
```

As this method is a workaround, an feature request has been raised to be able to install awscli without admin rights: https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/4633

Comment: I did this, it looked like it installed correctly, but when I use the command posted above it doesn't output anything. Can you elaborate on how to run the awscliv2?

Comment: Do you have an `aws` file present when you list files in `%USERPROFILE%\awscliv2\Amazon\AWSCLIV2` directory ? You can do this with `dir %USERPROFILE%\awscliv2\Amazon\AWSCLIV2` command. If there is an `aws` file in this directory, you have successfully extracted awscli v2 application. If so, did you execute the right command, you should remove the `>` prefix from command and execute `%USERPROFILE%\awscliv2\Amazon\AWSCLIV2\aws --version` command.

Comment: looks like I was using awscliv2/Amazon/...etc for the top level folder instead of awscli/Amazon/...etc. May want to amend your answer as I just followed all the directions verbatim. But its working now, thanks!

Comment: One last thing: you can use PowerShell's Set-Alias to get this to work as the regular aws command (like Linux): `Set-Alias -Name aws -Value "%USERPROFILE%/awscli/Amazon/AWSCLIV2/aws"`

Comment: Great hint, @j7skov! But, in Powershell, maybe you have to replace `%USERPROFILE%` with `~`?

Comment: @Charles - I had to use %USERPROFILE% because I installed aws on my C: drive in windows.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what 'Portable' level you're expecting, but you may find these resources helpful
[Chocolatey AWS Tools etc..](https://chocolatey.org/packages?q=AWS)

Or if you are using Docker
[Create a Docker image for the Amazon Web Services CLI that provides a portable, contained experience.](https://github.com/qualimente/docker-aws-cli)

Comment: Docker for Windows requires Windows 10 Pro or Enterprise, though. Also, "company laptops" with strict installation processes probably don't allow Docker

Comment: i guess something like this might work (not the docker) but the choco or just do it with python.
I was originally looking for a zip file, but after installing it I see that since it's so basic and lightweight that probably a portable version does not make sense

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried it using pip? if you have python available then:

For python version > 3.7

`$ python -m pip install awscli --user`

`$ aws`

```
Note: AWS CLI version 2, the latest major version of the AWS CLI, is now stable and recommended for general use. For more information, see the AWS CLI version 2 installation instructions at: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/install-cliv2.html

usage: aws [options] <command> <subcommand> [<subcommand> ...] [parameters]
To see help text, you can run:

  aws help
  aws <command> help
  aws <command> <subcommand> help
```